# Load multiple items with .load with multiple links

Tags: jquery, html

I want to load text inside my div of specific div from multiple links.

Like this is my HTML code

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

I can get text of specific div by link using following jquery.

```
$( "#mydiv" ).load( "http://website.com/events-1059278 .div1 .div2" );
```

Now I want to show multiple hundred of divs content in mydiv and want to show one div content per line.

Trying it but not work.

```
$( "#mydiv" ).load( "http://website.com/events-1059278 .div1 .div2, http://website.com/events-8477885 .div1 .div2,http://website.com/events-5481254 .div1 .div2" );
```

Preview should be show like this

Mr. ABC

Mr. DEF

Mr. GHI

Please let me know if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

.load() can get only 1 link at a time, so you can create an array with links list and then use a forEach loop to go through it.

Example:

```
var links = ["http://website.com/events-1059278 .div1 .div2", "http://website.com/events-8477885 .div1 .div2", "http://website.com/events-5481254 .div1 .div2"];

$(links).each(function(index, link) {
   $("#mydiv").load(link);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it. It is showing one text then suddenly 2nd then 3rd not showing all div text same time with one div content per line. Please help me.